# typeErrror : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'RCP_WEB') from module dependency

Tags: angular, typescript, typeerror, node-modules

I have created repo with some ts files which is having some methods and generated private registry for that repo. And installed & imported that as module dependency in my project (npm install modulename).
I could able to navigate/access methods from code.

```
import { AppName, getHotMenu, Language } from 'moduleName';

const webContent = getHotMenu({ features: this._appSession.metaData.features, appName: AppName.RCP_WEB, language: Language.ENGLISH});
```

But after compilation, i could not able to access anything from  that module, so getting

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'RCP_WEB')

Comment: can you also share how is `AppName` exported from `moduleName`? Try doing a `console.log(AppName)` to see what it refers to? If it is an exported variable from `moduleName`, is it initialized properly inside `moduleName`?

Comment: Yes.. Its properly initialized from moduleName. Even if we console the AppName, it will just print undefined

Comment: Properly initialized, still undefined... That's interesting!!! Can you share some code from `moduleName` demonstrating `AppName`?

Comment: AppName is nothing.. It just a export enum with few values